# How to speed up my boot time on 20.04

Tags: boot, startup

my boot time is taking over 4 mins to boot. i ran systemd-analyze blame and got the folowing:

```
1min 37.523s plymouth-quit-wait.service                         
1min 23.903s man-db.service                                     
     37.503s dev-sda1.device                                    
     29.774s snapd.service                                      
     24.693s networkd-dispatcher.service                        
     23.436s udisks2.service                                    
     20.326s logrotate.service                                  
     20.022s dev-loop33.device                                  
     18.972s dev-loop34.device                                  
     18.618s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                 
     18.058s dev-loop21.device                                  
     17.726s dev-loop11.device                                  
     17.686s dev-loop29.device                                  
     17.437s dev-loop31.device                                  
     17.431s dev-loop35.device                                  
     17.227s dev-loop36.device                                  
     17.154s dev-loop32.device                                  
     16.952s dev-loop10.device                                  
     16.944s dev-loop30.device                                  
     16.944s dev-loop27.device                                  
     16.319s dev-loop26.device                                  
     16.264s dev-loop25.device                                  
     15.930s accounts-daemon.service
```

Any idea how to improve this??

Comment: What is the hardware?

Comment: It's taking 37.5 seconds to mount your /dev/sda1. Check your /etc/fstab.

Comment: Hardware is a dell laptop, with intel i5 16gb.

Comment: How do i check/etc/fstab ??